# How to set up API gateway without specifying all resources

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, routes, aws-api-gateway

I have some EC 2 applications (in node.js) that have many REST paths, and since still in development process, the path keep changing.

How can I set up in the api-gateway, that will map to multiple paths, instead of specify each of them?

```
e.g. 
my ec2 end points have:
my.ec2.com/api/test
my.ec2.com/api/test1
my.ec2.com/api/test2
my.ec2.com/api/user/time
my.ec2.com/api/user/time1
my.ec2.com/api/user/time2
```

instead of setting the all resources in api-gateway,
can I do something like:
api-gateway.amazon.com/api  that points to my.ec2.com/api/

and it will resolve any call to http://api-gateway.amazon.com/api/test  automatically points to http://my.ec2.com/api/test,  etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, it is still impossible in the API gateway console.

The solution is to use Swagger.  then I can use some scripts to generate the Swagger file and import to API gateway.  In fact, it is a good solution because I can source control on Swagger.